# JavaScript reduce method behaving strangely when we pass a function with one argument

Tags: javascript, methods, reduce

JavaScript noob here. I've got no clue how the map1 is calculated, I've changed every element of array1 one at a time, and map1 still prints as -8. Has anyone got any link to a detailed explanation of the reduce() method? I've found none! Or can anyone please explain what's happening?

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.reduce(x => x - 2, 0);
console.log(map1); // shows -8
```

Comment: the result is completely independent of the array's values. you may have a look to [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)'s accumulator. it has a start value of zero and for every iteration it is decrement by two.

Comment: nothing strange here since you're passing only the accumulator and substracting **2** four times (the length of the array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript,`reduce` accepts

- a callback function as first argument.
- an **initial value** for **accumulator** as second argument

```
array1.reduce(() => {}, initialValue);
```

This callback has mainly two parameters

- first param = accumulator
- second param = current value

Accumulator is just like a box which get whatever value is returned from a previous iteration.
We can use this to add things from every single iteration.

So lets see a basic example:

```
const initialValue = 0
const answer = [1,2,3,4].reduce((acc, curr) => {

}, initialValue);
console.log('answer: ', answer);
```

Here we have **callback function** which **returns nothing.**

Let's see the code execution flow for this example

For the first iteration, **accumulator** is set to **0**,
Since **we aren't return anything**, **undefined is being returned** from every iteration which sets **`acc` = undefined** on every iteration.

**when all 4 iterations are completed, that** accumulator is returned. (which is undefined in this case)

**Example 2:**

```
const initialValue = 0
const answer = [1,2,3,4].reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc - 2; 
}, initialValue);
console.log('answer: ', answer);
```

In **First Iteration**, `acc` = 0 due to initial value **but at the end of this iteration, it return a value which is 0-2 = -2**. **`acc` is set to -2.**

**second iteration**, `acc`-2 becomes -2-2 = -4.

**third iteration**, `acc`-2 becomes -4-2 = -6.

**fourth iteration**, `acc`-2 becomes -6-2 = -8. (last iteration, so `acc is returned and we get -8 as final result)

since we are using **arrow functions**, **you can remove the brackets '{' '}' and '`return`' keyword by writing it in single line** as

```
const initialValue = 0
const answer = [1,2,3,4].reduce((acc, curr) => acc - 2 , initialValue);
console.log('answer: ', answer);
```

**Both of the last two code are exactly the same** with only the difference of **syntactic sugar**.

Hope this helps, have any questions please ask.

Comment: up'ed for showing more clearly that the "initialValue" is a `reduce` function parameter, not a parameter of  the  "reducingFunction"

Answer (score 2):

Nothing strange here. Look to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

What are you passing here is `previousValue` (or `accumulator`) with inital value as 0. Every iteration you just ignore elements from array and return `previousValue - 2`. Here are 4 iterations so returned value is -8.

Answer (score 0):

So put it simply, reduce takes in multiple values. First one being the previous value(in this case 0), second is the comparable value(newValue), then comes index and array.

```
const map1 = array1.reduce((prevValue, newValue) => newValue - 2, 0);
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce